# %like% query not giving result as expected

Tags: php, sql, laravel, search, laravel-5.3

i'm working on search functionality, i'm querying based on the user input but i'm not getting the result as expected

```
//if user searches walter getting proper response

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search/walter  

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Walter",
      "last_name": "White",
      "phone_number": "9665885542",
      "registration_id": "12345b67892"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "first_name": "Mitty",
      "last_name": "Walter",
      "phone_number": "8826835542",
      "registration_id": "dffdfg54ty45y"
    }
  ]
}

// but if user searches walt the response is

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search/walt  

{
  "data": []
}
```

my method

//search Drivers
public function getSearchResults($search_input) {

```
$search_drivers = Driver::where('id', 'like', $search_input)
                 ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', $search_input)
                 ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', $search_input)
                 ->orWhere('phone_number', 'like', $search_input)
                 ->orWhere('registration_id', 'like', $search_input)
                 ->select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_id')
                 ->get();

return Response::json([
    'data' => $search_drivers
]);
```

}

is there any better way to get results before entering full data

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for [`like`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) is `'%'.$search_input.'%'`:

```
$search_drivers = Driver::where('id', 'like', '%'.$search_input.'%')
     ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%'.$search_input.'%')
     ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$search_input.'%')
     ->orWhere('phone_number', 'like', '%'.$search_input.'%')
     ->orWhere('registration_id', 'like', '%'.$search_input.'%')
     ->select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_id')
     ->get();
```

Comment: my bad, thank you so much really appreciate it, i cant accept the answer in 6mins  says stackoverflow